# how to fix the SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE] wrong signature type (_ssl.c:1002)')))

Tags: python, python-requests, html-parsing

I was practicing scraping and chose a site https://www.amalgama-lab.com/songs/m/marilyn_manson/tainted_love.html
when I try to get a get request to this site, I get SSL: WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE. I think I'm doing something wrong because I don't understand
[screenshot of code and console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roAas.png)
OS Windows 10

I tried to set verify=False - it did not help, I tried to copy pool_manager, as advised in other answers - it did not help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The site is not using TLS1.2, you've to check which TLS version it's using.

Comment: I have really good solution here https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1539710/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-wrong-signature-type-ssl-c1002-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d1%83/1539899#1539899

Answer (score -1):

```py
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1'
r = requests.get(
    'https://www.amalgama-lab.com/songs/m/marilyn_manson/tainted_love.html')
print(r)
```

Comment: I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.